# Vuejs radio button binding input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am creating edit form page and i run this before the page loaded

```
beforeMount(){
    if(this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit'){
        this.initialize = '/api/artikel/edit/' + this.$route.params.id;
        this.store = '/api/artikel/update/' + this.$route.params.id;
        this.method = 'put';
    }
    this.fetchData();
},
```

and in my fetchData() method i just go to server and retrieve corresponding data to my article id.

```
fetchData(){
    var vm = this
    axios.get(this.initialize)
        .then(function(response){
            Vue.set(vm.$data, 'form', response.data.form);
            Vue.set(vm.$data, 'rules', response.data.rules);
            Vue.set(vm.$data, 'option', response.data.option);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
        })
},
```

and then in my form i just bind my form data to my input and it works great in input text but not in other like in this question is input radio button

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h5>Publish:</h5>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="publish" class="styled" value="1" v-model="form.publish">
        Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="publish" class="styled" value="0" v-model="form.publish">
        No
    </label>
</div>
```

it supposed to be auto check into radio button according to the value from database... but in my case none of them checked.. but when i check manualy by clicking it... i see using the form.publish value is changed according to which radio button i check using vuejs inspector in chrome

so where do i get it wrong?

Comment: The radio buttons are bound to `form.publish`. You don't set `form.publish` in the callback.

Comment: i set the form.publish in fetchdata methods, in there my backend return a json object that inside it contains publish... so it only make sense to call it form.publish

Answer (score 0):

Might be a matter of how the value is coming in. Because you set values to 0/1 the radio button model needs a 0 or 1 value, and not a true/false, can you check that that's the case?

look at snipped below, see what changing to true does

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {}
  },
  methods: {
    update () {
      // does not work
      //var form = { publish: true } 
      // works
      var form = { publish: 1 } // <---- are you sure it's 1 and not true?
      this.$set(this, 'form', form);
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.form)
    setTimeout(this.update, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.8/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
      <h5>Publish:</h5>
      <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="publish" class="styled" value="1" v-model="form.publish">
          Yes
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="publish" class="styled" value="0" v-model="form.publish">
          No
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i am certain the value that come from database is 0/1 and i also tried your example by switching to true/false value but none of them working...

Comment: the code above is using a timeout of 1 second, and should set the radio box to true. This is the example boiled down to the simplest. (I've also tried it with `Vue.set(vm.$data, 'form', form);` and it still works). Can you include what `{{form}}` is showing? whare did you define `fetchData` ? is it a method?

Comment: fetchData is a methods and what included in form is json object that returned from database. in my form i also have input text that bind with v-model and those part is working fine

Answer (score 0):

okay my bad.... it is not a problem with vue.js but instead because i am using [uniform.js](https://github.com/square/uniform) for my radio button styling from admin template that i bought in themeforest and they don't provide a clear documentation...

and after searching around i find that the javascript and css that style my radiobutton is by uniform.js and i just add a jquery code to run update the radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted few hours, and later got to know, I was missing `:checked="item.isActive == true"` property while binding. Adding this worked for me.

```
                    <input
                      class="form-check-input"
                      type="radio"
                      name="students"
                      v-model="item.isActive"
                      :checked="item.isActive== true">
```